# Page Object Model Returning Action Instead of Object?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Picking up a Java-Selenium framework, and noticed that the previous owner has a lot of page object models that are defined as java classes, but instead of returning a `driver.findElement()`, they are returning a `driver.findElement().click();`

EDIT: You guys are correct it's not returning per say

`public void leftnav_home_link() { driver.findElement().click(); }`

I've never seen this before, but is this valid/follows the ideals of a page object model?

What kind of potential problems can this lead into?

Comment: Can you please post a full method showing/explaining what you mean?

Comment: I doubt they are "returning" it, because it's a `void` method, Java would complain saying you cannot return a `void` method...so I assume you are just misunderstanding the code. If it's the last line in a method, it is not a "return", for instance.

Comment: We have also never seen this before (returning void). Can u please update ques with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of page objects, if the 'action' you refer to is a action to the next page, the normal thing would be to have a PageObjectX class with a normal constructor and a click method returning the next page object.   The click method might be implemented like this, which is not unusual:

```
public class PageObjectX extends LoadableComponent {
    private final WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(id = "go") private WebElement goB;
    PageObjectX {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void load() {
      driver.get("http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry");
    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
      String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
      assertTrue("Not on the issue entry page: " + url, url.endsWith("/entry"));
    }

    public PageObjectY clickGoToY() {
            driver.findElement( goB );
            return new PageObjectY();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your answer on this. If the action is defined, then we should be able to contain an action within a page object. If an element is defined, however, then we should return that element. Being able to distinguish between the two needs to be done clearly, and I think that's where things are getting weird for me here.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense, since according to the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.java#78), `click()` on a `WebElement` just executes the remote driver command and returns nothing:

```
public void click() {
    execute(DriverCommand.CLICK_ELEMENT, ImmutableMap.of("id", id));
}
```